# Bootstrap Dropdown Menu close

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap  dropdown menu. I need the function to close when I click on the menu items.

The link going like ajax request model, So the page is not refreshing.

```
<li class="dropdown">
  <a href="link"  ng-class="isOurProducts" data-toggle="dropdown" id="products">Product<b class="caret"></b></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="globe.html">globe</a></li>
    <li><a href="safe.html">Safe</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use like this.

$(document).on('click','.navbar-collapse.in',function(e) {
    if( $(e.target).is('a') ) {
        $(this).collapse('hide');
    }
});
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: The website navigation is working with Angular JS. When I click on any of the dropdown menu. The dropdown need to close.

Comment: let me show the only ul and ul parent class so that i could give you some suggestion